# Issue in DiffableDataSource tableview header

Tags: swift, uitableview, diffabledatasource

I'm using the tableView using DiffableDataSource and only issue which I've faced in header.I'm using viewForheaderSections method for calling header header view appear but on bottom position not top of the list please see the code thanks.

```
extension SinlgeTableViewcontroller:UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: Header.self)) as? Header else {return UIView()}
        cell.lblHeader.text = "Top Mens"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
    
    func createDataSource(){
        dataSource = UITableViewDiffableDataSource<ProductsSections,AnyHashable>(tableView: tableView, cellProvider: { tableView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            switch self.sectionsData[indexPath.section]{
                case .first:
                    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: ProductCell.self)) as? ProductCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
                    cell.products = self.products[indexPath.row]
                    return cell
                case .second:
                    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: MensCell.self)) as? MensCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
                    cell.mens = self.mens[indexPath.row]
                    return cell
            }
        })
        
    }
    
    func createSnapshot(){
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<ProductsSections,AnyHashable>()
        sectionsData.forEach{ $0
            snapshot.appendSections([$0])
        }
      //  snapshot.appendSections([.first,.second])
        snapshot.appendItems(products, toSection: .first)
        snapshot.appendItems(mens, toSection: .second)
        dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you are not using `viewForHeaderInSection`. Instead of that you are using `viewForFooterInSection`. So instead of a `header`, a `footer` will appear in the bottom.

If you only need a `header` change all the methods related to the `footer` to the `header`.